# How to call multiple client apis using HttpClient in .net and .net core

Tags: .net-core, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, rest-client

In my one of the .net core project I have to call REST apis to send some data to clients. There are always more than 9-10 clients with different apis having their own domain and custom headers. If I will create HttpClient object each time it will hamper performance since each time new TCP connection will be create and closed. If I will create single HttpClient object using singleton designing pattern then same base url and default header will be used for each client. Can any one suggest a way to solve this problem. I do not wants to go and create new HttpClient every time new client api comes for integration.

Comment: We can help you sort out your code if you paste it in a fiddle?

Comment: I have still not written actual code. But this is sample which i was planning to use.
Here url can be api of any client
public Output CallApi(string url)
{
 var _httpClient = SingletonHttpClient.Instance;
 
 if(_httpClient != null)
 {
  using (var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result)
  {
   return response.Content.ConvertToObject<Output>().Result;
  }
 }
 
 return null;
}

Comment: @ToddMenier Thanks. You have given very good suggestion

Answer (score 3):

If you're calling 9-10 different APIs, where client-level things like default headers could come in handy, then 9-10 static `HttpClient` instances is optimal. If coding 9-10 instances feels a little messy/repetitive, you could wrap them in a dictionary object, specifically a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) will help keep instantiation both lazy and thread-safe. Something like this should work:

```
public static class HttpClientManager
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpClient> _clients = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpClient>();

    public static HttpClient Get(string baseUrl)
    {
        return _clients.GetOrAdd(baseUrl, _ =>
            new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) });
    }
}
```

Then it's just `HttpClientManager.Get(baseUrl)` whenever you need to use one.